# How to migrate Product custom options records from magento 1.7 to magento 2.x in product edit, order, invoice,Shipment and Credit memo?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7, custom-options, data-migration

I looking for the migrate Product custom options records from magento 1.7 to magento 2.x
I have have migrated all the data from magento 1.7 to magento 2.2.6, but custom options not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the product editing page to see whether custom options are showing. If they are there but not on the front end, go checking the catalog_product_entity table. In this table, there is a has_option field, this field must be set to 1 in order for the custom options to show up

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I want to show custom options in order, invoice,Shipment and Credit memo in back-end and Front-end

Comment: Then, please check the sales_order_item table to see if product_options collumn already has data or not. If yes:
For Magento version < 2.2, it has to be one serialize string.
For Magento version > 2.2, it's a json string